# Solve equations with sympy e numpy in python

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I'm trying to solve a system of equations that should have (infinity)^1 solution. But I get only the solution trivial solution.
This is the system:

[image]

The matrix A is defined as follow:

[image]

From the first equation follow that the system has (infinity)^1 solutions.
The code I implemented in python is:

```
A = np.matrix([[0.15, 0.15, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4],
 [0, 0.55, 0, 0, 0.45],
 [0.3, 0.05, 0.05, 0, 0.6],
 [0, 0.4, 0.1, 0.5, 0],
 [0, 0.3, 0, 0, 0.7]])
w1, w2, w3, w4, w5 = symbols('w1 w2 w3 w4 w5')
w = [w1, w2, w3, w4, w5]

p = np.dot(w, A)

eq1 = Eq(p.item(0), w[0])
eq2 = Eq(p.item(1), w[1])
eq3 = Eq(p.item(2), w[2])
eq4 = Eq(p.item(3), w[3])
eq5 = Eq(p.item(4), w[4])
sol = solve([eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5])
```

but I get `sol = {w1: 0.0, w2: 0.0, w3: 0.0, w4: 0.0, w5: 0.0}` instead the correct solution should be something like

[image]

Furthermore, I have to impose that
w1+w2+w3+w4+w5 = 1;
So in conclusion, the solution should be

w1 =w3 = w4 = 0 and w2= 0.2,w5=0.6

but when I change code to include the last equations in this way:

```
A = np.matrix([[0.15, 0.15, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4],
 [0, 0.55, 0, 0, 0.45],
 [0.3, 0.05, 0.05, 0, 0.6],
 [0, 0.4, 0.1, 0.5, 0],
 [0, 0.3, 0, 0, 0.7]])
w1, w2, w3, w4, w5 = symbols('w1 w2 w3 w4 w5')
w = [w1, w2, w3, w4, w5]

p = np.dot(w, A)

eq1 = Eq(p.item(0), w[0])
eq2 = Eq(p.item(1), w[1])
eq3 = Eq(p.item(2), w[2])
eq4 = Eq(p.item(3), w[3])
eq5 = Eq(p.item(4), w[4])
eq6 = Eq(w1+w2+w3+w4+w5=1)
sol = solve([eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6])
```

I still get the wrong solution, in fact I get `sol = []`

I can't understand where I'm going wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

The thing is you are using floating points values, and, as you said, the rank of your matrix is less than its dimension. Said otherwise, you have a redundant equation. Which is not a solution (since you can't just remove one equation randomly), but an explanation.

Try to solve only the 4 first equations

```py
solve([eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4])
```

And you get what you expected

```
{w1: 0.0, w2: 0.666666666666667*w5, w3: 0.0, w4: 0.0}
```

Or almost so. You said 2/5, and it's 2/3, but I guess you made an error somewhere. You can easily check that `np.array([0,2/3,0,0,1])@A` is indeed `[0,2/3,0,0,1]`, when `np.array([0,2/5,0,0,1]) @ A` is not `[0,2/5,0,0,1]`.

Again, not a solution. It happens to work here, because eq5 happens to be redundant. But you can't assume that.

But let's check equation 5.

```
0.4*w1 + 0.45*w2 + 0.6*w3 + 0.7*w5 = w5
```

Together with what we have, that is w2=2/3w5, and w1=w3=w4=0, equation 5 becomes

```
0.45*2/3*w5 + 0.7*w5 = w5
```

So, it is indeed `0.3*w5+0.7*w5=w5` <=> `w5=wg` a redundant equation.

Except that you are using floating point values.
So, in reality, what we had after solving the 1st 4 equation is

```
w2=0.666666666666667*w5
```

And `0.45*0.666666666666667*w5 + 0.7*w5` is not exactly w5. Ok, if you type that in python, you get 1, because we get lukcy with rounding. But that is not necessary what happens when sympy solve. For example, if I had solved first `eq1, eq2, eq3, eq5` and let eq4 for the end, the problem would have been more obvious (but my message more painful to write)

```py
solve([eq1,eq2,eq3,eq5])
```

```
{w1: 3.48077760823041e-18*w5, w2: 0.666666666666667*w5, w3: 9.86220322331948e-18*w5, w4: 9.02101530133047e-17*w5}
```

So, at the end, sympy, with all 5 equations, endup trying to solve

```
0.99999999999999999*w5 = w5
```

Which has only 1 solution (w5=0), strictly speaking.

### Solution

You must use an exact type for sympy to be able to have an exact (useless, but that an information) `w5=w5` equation remaining.

One way is to use integers, which, in your case, is feasible.

```py
A100=(100*A).round().astype(np.int)
```

is matrix 100A, with integer values (so, not 45.0 or so, but 45)

So w.A100 is

```py
p=w@A100
```

(Just taking advantage of the situation to introduce '@' operator here. But that is the same as your `np.dot(w, A100)`

And now, we can use your equations, that are not `p.item(?) = w[?]` but `p.item(?) = 100*w[?]` since p is 100.wᵀA, not wᵀA

```py
equations = [Eq(p.item(i), 100*w[i]) for i in range(len(w))]
# Again, I take advantage of the occasion to show how to compact things,
# but I could have also wrote, as you did
# eq1 = Eq(p.item(0), 100*w[0])
# eq2 ...
```

And now, we just have to solve that

```py
solve(equations)
```

to get the answer

```
{w1: 0, w2: 2*w5/3, w3: 0, w4: 0}
```

Or, adding your extra constraint

```py
equations.append(Eq(w1+w2+w3+w4+w5, 1))
# Note: you wrote "=" but you obviously meant ","
solve(equations)
```

which gives

```
{w1: 0, w2: 2/5, w3: 0, w4: 0, w5: 3/5}
```

So all together

```py
from sympy import solve, Eq, symbols
import numpy as np

A = np.matrix([[0.15, 0.15, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4],
 [0, 0.55, 0, 0, 0.45],
 [0.3, 0.05, 0.05, 0, 0.6],
 [0, 0.4, 0.1, 0.5, 0],
 [0, 0.3, 0, 0, 0.7]])

A100=(100*A).round().astype(np.int)

w1, w2, w3, w4, w5 = symbols('w1 w2 w3 w4 w5')
w = [w1, w2, w3, w4, w5]
p=w@A100
equations = [Eq(p.item(i), 100*w[i]) for i in range(len(w))]

# General solution without constraint
print(solve(equations))

equations.append(Eq(w1+w2+w3+w4+w5, 1))
# With constraint
print(solve(equations))
```

### Note

If your objective was to play with sympy, fine. That's a noble objective (and if I answered, lengthily, to your question, that was in the same objective, since I discovered sympy by anwering to another question a few days ago).

But, if your objective was just to find the solution to wᵀA=wᵀ, well, that is overkill.

You have two, pure numerical solutions (that wouldn't have put you in that trouble about exact values) to do so, without symbolic computation.

### 1st other solution

One, would be to find the null space of w↦wᵀA-wᵀ, that is, as you said of w↦wᵀ(A-I).
And wᵀ(A-I) = ((A-I)ᵀwᵀᵀ)ᵀ. So, this is 0, when (A-I)ᵀw=0. Said otherwise, you are just searching the null space of (A-I)ᵀ

Which is done easily with

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import null_space
A = np.matrix([[0.15, 0.15, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4],
 [0, 0.55, 0, 0, 0.45],
 [0.3, 0.05, 0.05, 0, 0.6],
 [0, 0.4, 0.1, 0.5, 0],
 [0, 0.3, 0, 0, 0.7]])
I=np.identity(len(A))
ker=null_space((A-I).T)
print(ker)
```

Which gives

```
[[-0.00000000e+00]
 [-5.54700196e-01]
 [ 1.66533454e-16]
 [-1.26287869e-15]
 [-8.32050294e-01]]
```

Which you can then easily normalize for your extra constraint

```py
print(ker/ker.sum())
```

```
array([[ 0.00000000e+00],
       [ 4.00000000e-01],
       [-1.20088981e-16],
       [ 9.10674775e-16],
       [ 6.00000000e-01]])
```

Note that this is a 2D array, because you could have had ∞²,∞³, ... solutions, not necessarily the ∞¹ you announced at first

And note that this time, it is a numerical solution. So, no problem with exactitude (and, the given solutions contains some 10⁻¹⁶ that you have to decide to ignore.

### 2nd other solution

wᵀA = wᵀ, is the same as Aᵀw = w. So what you are searching is whether 1 is a eigen value of Aᵀ, and, if so, you want the eigenspace associated.

You can also do that with numpy

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as lin
A = np.matrix([[0.15, 0.15, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4],
 [0, 0.55, 0, 0, 0.45],
 [0.3, 0.05, 0.05, 0, 0.6],
 [0, 0.4, 0.1, 0.5, 0],
 [0, 0.3, 0, 0, 0.7]])
lin.eig(A.T)
```

gives

```
(
array([ 1.        ,  0.53771372, -0.04671525,  0.25      , 0.20900153]), 
matrix([[-1.01241e-16, -1.04493e-01,  7.97421e-01, -2.28843e-15, -1.03239e-01],
        [-5.54700e-01, -2.07800e-02,  6.08791e-02,  7.07106e-01, -6.74602e-01],
        [-5.61815e-17, -1.35044e-01, -5.22882e-01, -7.15136e-16, -2.03043e-02],
        [-1.65466e-16, -5.54139e-01, -2.91713e-01,  9.68185e-16,  7.09556e-02],
        [-8.32050e-01,  8.14457e-01, -4.37037e-02, -7.07106e-01,  7.27190e-01]]))
```

(I removed 3 decimals to that it displays nicely)

So you get 5 eigen values (the 5 λ such as wᵀA=λwᵀ has non-zero solutions). Some may be complex (if diagonalisation in ℝ is not possible), but one, at least, should be 1, or almost so. The associated eigen vector(s), that is the column(s) of the following matrix, is (are. "is" here, because you have ∞¹ solutions) the one you are looking for (the same one we got from null_space(A.T-I). Which is not surprising, given that one definition of eigenspace associated with eigenvalue λ of matrix M is Eλ=Ker(M-λI))